# ngx-filter-pipe está retornando o index errado do meu *ngFor quando elemento é filtrado

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho um pipe que realiza um filtro no meu `*ngFor`:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="anunciosFiltro.name" type="text" name="filtra" id="filtra">

<tr *ngFor="let anuncio of sortedData | filterBy: anunciosFiltro; let i = index">
```

TS:

```
anunciosFiltro: any = { name: '' };
```

Acontece que dentro do `*ngFor` tenho um botão de editar que usa o index desse `*ngFor`, quando eu filtro e traz apenas um produto, ele pega o index 0, mas na verdade o index desse produto no array `sortedData` é 4.

Há alguma forma de pegar o index correto?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Sim, eu tinha um método editaAnuncio(sortedData[i]), alterei para editaAnuncio(anuncio), funcionou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já que está querendo apenas pegar o índice do Arr, você pode utilizar o pipe `keyvalue`! Tente o seguinte:

```
<tr *ngFor="let anuncio of sortedData | keyvalue">
```

Caso queira manter a ordem do índice, poderás adicionar uma pequena função no seu arquivo `.ts` para fazer o trabalho sujo;

```
<tr *ngFor="let anuncio of sortedData | keyvalue:keepOder">
```

TS

```
public keepOrder = (a,b) => a.key;
```

Utilize `anuncio.key` para recuperar o índice desejado!!!